# Possible solutions to monitor a DateTime Column in a SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms

I have a DateTime column in `ACTIVITY` Table(SQL) which can take values of future `DateTime`. I need to inspect `DateTime` column in `ACTIVITY` table if the future `datetime` is reached in the background asynchronously.

Background worker is one of the options to achieve this where I can query the table column. I would like to know if there are any better alternatives to do the same.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: SQL Agent/Jobs in SQL Server or Event Scheduler in MySQL, Oracle has a built in Scheduler ...

Comment: How time sensitive is it?  Do you need to run application code based on the result?  Windows Task scheduler is generally better than polling within a service when possible.

Comment: Well something in your application is updating that column, so why can't your application raise another event if the condition is satisfied? I don't seen any reason why you need to mess around with anything built into sql server.